# Ruby on Rails ajax modal window returning 500 status code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I'm trying to learn how to do a customized modal window, but I'm getting an error 500 status code.

I have this in my view: **views/dashboard/index.html.haml**

```
.container
  - @trips.each do |trip|
    = link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path, remote: true
  .quick-view{style: "display:none;"}
    = render "trips/quick_view"
```

I'm not sure if quick_view_trips_path is correct. I'm trying to show content of the trips in the modal window.

In addition, I have these:

**views/trips/quick_view.js.erb**

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "views/trips/quick_view" %>');
```

**views/trips/_quick_view.html.haml**

```
.root-container
  = @trip.title
  = @trip.image
  = @trip.more_details
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :trips do
  collection do
    get 'quick_view'
  end
end
```

**trips_controller.rb**

```
def quick_view
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # quick_view.html.erb
    format.js # quick_view.js.erb
    format.json { render json: @trip }
  end
end
```

EDIT: Error from console

Oh, I just realized that I was able to see the error if I click on the link `http://localhost:3000/trips/quick_view` in the console:

It says `ActionView::MissingTemplate at /trips/quick_view`

```
Missing partial views/trips/_quick_view with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}.
```

Comment: can you post the entire 500 error?

Comment: do you see quick_view_trips as a prefix when you run ```rake routes``` ?

Comment: @MilesStanfield It says Its missing template, but I have `_quick_view.html.haml` and `quick_view.js.erb`

Comment: `render partial: "trips/quick_view"`

Comment: @RajarshiDas WOAH! I DID IT!! woohoo thanks! What is the correct way to send the correct trip data into the model tho? The reason why I wasn't sure about `quick_view_trips_path` is because, this seems like a static url page

Comment: if my post help you then can you please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `render partial:`instead `render` only as your view is `_quick_view.html.haml` not `quick_view.html.haml`

```
.container
  - @trips.each do |trip|
    = link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path, remote: true
  .quick-view{style: "display:none;"}
    = render partial: "trips/quick_view"
```

and in js not required `views` as

```
  $('body').append('<%= j render partial: "trips/quick_view" %>');
```

If you wan to fetch the content of a particular modal and replace it like here every click will appen the each trip quick view to the body by whn each time click the link `remote: true`it will call the controller method and that will response as format of `js` so it will call `quick_view.js.erb` and append the trip by fetching the partial.

So here

```
link_to trip.id, quick_view_trips_path, remote: true
```

will call `trips/quick_view.js.erb` as it is telling a ajax request to response by `remote: true`

so in `quick_view.js.erb`

we append the `partial` in `body` by jQuery method `append` and we use `j render` where `j` or `escape_javascript` use for  "Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments" (quote from the Rails docs)

Comment: It was the JS file that was wrong... that should've been `trips/quick_view` instead of `views/trips/quick_view`. However, before I accept this answer, you think you can see what it is the right way to pass dynamic content into the modal?

Comment: yes right I update...I am really glad to help you on christmass :))

Comment: Just quick question: can you explain the dynamic content that will be passed? This maybe helpful for someone else as well

Comment: yes you mean by the js render your partial this one?

Comment: Yeah, so because I have dynamic trips within the .each loop, and if a user clicks on certain links, it should populate the modal based on the link user clicks on, and how would I display the content?

Comment: Hello, thanks for explanation, I think the issue I'm having is when I do `@trip.title` and such is I'm getting `undefined method nil`. I don't think anything information is passed into the `_quick_view.html.haml` page. If user clicks on a `trip.id` that is `1` or a `trip.id` that is `5`, the content will be the same.